# How can I serialize case classes to tab delimited text files?

Tags: scala, data-structures, file-io

I have a List the contains case classes of the same type, I am looking for the best practice in persisting it to a text file with tab delimited

```
case class mycase1 (x: Int, y:Int , name:String)  
val item1 = new mycase1(1,2,"item1")
val item2 = new mycase1(3,4,"item2")
val item3 = new mycase1(5,6,"item3")

val myList = List (item1,item2,item3)
```

What is the best way to write the above data structure to a file ? is there such a thing as :

```
myList.toFile(delimiter="\t")
```

Comment: As a Scala tip, no need of 'new' keyword to create an instance of case class. mycase1(1, 2, "item1") would suffice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because a case class is a `Product`, you can simply use the `productIterator` method to get the fields in the order they were defined in an iterator.  You can use that and `map` the List of `mycase1` to a List of `String` and then use that to write to a file.  A simplified example would look like this:

```
  case class mycase1 (x: Int, y:Int , name:String)  
  val item1 = new mycase1(1,2,"item1")
  val item2 = new mycase1(3,4,"item2")
  val item3 = new mycase1(5,6,"item3")

  val myList = List (item1,item2,item3)

  val out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(pathToMyFile))
  try{
    myList.map(_.productIterator.mkString("\t")) foreach (out.println(_))      
  }
  finally{
    out.close
  }
```

The only caveat is that the fields do get outputted in the order they are defined (left to right) in the case class constructor.  If you want it another way, my solution will not work.

Comment: You don't need to first transform the elements of the list and then print them, you can do that at the same time : `myList.foreach{e => out.println(e.productIterator.mkString("\t"))}`

Comment: Of course you can, but the approach provided in the answer is called "deferring side effects", that way the side effect (printing out) happens later (in other words put side-effect-free code in `map` and use `foreach` only for side effects)